# ArcGIS raster ASCII range not displaying as expected?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-ascii-raster

On ArcGIS, I have initially used the mosaic feature to join a number of .asc files. The mosaic output displays the same range (max and min) of these .asc files. I  now need to convert the raster mosaic file to an ascii file but for some reason the output of this conversion is displaying a different range. This is a bit strange to me  (I must say that I am  not a gis expert).

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Calculate the statistics http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/0017/0017000000m3000000.htm on the output ASCII file to ensure your min/max is correct.

Comment: Check spatial extent and cell size settings.

Comment: I have computed the statistics of the .ascii (asc) file. Essentially Arcgis have created a new .asc file (the "older" has been converted to xml) where the  statistics are basically coincident (as well as the cell size settings) with the mosaic output. This basically proves that the initial output was correct, but I am not sure the reason why this extra step was needed in this case. Thanks.